# Sending message from background script to content script (multiple browsers)

Tags: javascript, message, firefox-addon-webextensions, content-script

I have a working prototype of an extension that works on Chrome but when I try to run it on Firefox i get the following error:

```
Unchecked lastError value: Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

I use this code to differentiate between browsers:

```
window.namespace = (function () {
return window.msBrowser ||
    window.browser ||
    window.chrome;
})();
```

the following part is to detect when the user clicks on the extension icon (so that I know to activate it):

```
let show_floater = false;          // to know if extension should be active

window.namespace.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    buttonClicked(tab);
});

function buttonClicked(tab) {
    show_floater = !show_floater;

    console.log('coding intensifies');

    // Send message to content_script of tab.id
    window.namespace.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, show_floater);  // <-- ERROR IS HERE
}
```

All this code is in my background script.

The handling of the message in my content script is as follows

```
window.namespace.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);

let injected = false;

function gotMessage(show_floater, sender, sendResponse) {
     // Here I just do stuff
     console.log("I'm working here!");
}
```

---

Online I saw that people that had this problem usually did not include <all_urls> in the manifest. In my case I already had that so I'm kinda lost here. From my understanding both Chrome and Firefox should use the same methods to send and receive messages. Is my way of distinguishing between browsers flawed?

**CHANGES**

[Here](https://www.bennettnotes.com/post/fix-receiving-end-does-not-exist/) I found a solution.

Background:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (event) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: 'js/content.js', /* my content script */   }, () => {
        connect() //this is where I call my function to establish a 
connection     });
    });
});

function connect() {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
        const port = chrome.tabs.connect(tabs[0].id);

        show_floater = !show_floater;

        port.postMessage(show_floater);
        // port.onMessage.addListener((response) => {
        //     html = response.html;
        //     title = response.title;
        //     description = response.description;
        // });
    });
```

contentscript:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener((port) => {
     port.onMessage.addListener((show_floater) => {
          else if (!injected) {
           injected = true;

           let link = document.createElement("link");
           link.className = 'beebole_css';
           link.href = "https://localhost/css/test.css";
           link.type = "text/css";
           link.rel = "stylesheet";
           document.querySelector("head").appendChild(link);

           let s = document.createElement("script");
           s.className = 'beebole_js';
           s.src = "https://localhost/js/test.js";
           s.type = 'text/javascript';
           // document.body.appendChild(s);
           document.querySelector('body').appendChild(s);
      }
     });
});
```

Again, this code works perfectly on Chrome but on Firefox it give the following error:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://localhost/js/test.js”.
```

Comment: The error is saying there's no content script running at all or onMessage listener wasn't actually registered. Use devtools to verify the former (either enable an option to debug addons or just add a console.log to the beginning of the content script).

Comment: @wOxxOm I already did try that and the console.log shows. So from what i can see it runs the content script but fails to load the listener somehow D:

Comment: Well, your approach to dealing with namespace isn't standard but it doesn't look immediately wrong so you'll have to debug. Do it the divide-and-conquer way to eliminate the complexity you've added: start by using `chrome` instead of `window.namespace`, then try `browser`.

Comment: with chrome it works perfectly, in fact running it on the Chrome browsers results in no issues at all. So I assume that it's browser that causes problems. But I will test to be sure

Comment: @wOxxOm using browser results in the same error. There must be a difference in how Firefox and chrome handle messages but I am kinda new to js so I'm way out of my depth here

Comment: You can use `chrome` namespace in Firefox.

Comment: @wOxxOm cool I didn't know. Does it work also for IE? But even with chrome it does not work on Firefox. Works like a charm on Chrome tho...

Comment: IE doesn't support chrome extensions or WebExtension so it's not relevant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225024/discussion-between-stefano-pozzi-and-woxxom).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill for cross browser compatibility.